# loading .dat into R, no column names

Tags: r, fixed-width

I am having trouble reading a large .dat file into R.

I am using

```
data <- read.table("...2018029_ascii/FRSS108PUF.dat", fill=TRUE)
```

This results in a large dataframe with V1, V2 as column names.

I am using the ASCII file at this link: https://nces.ed.gov/pubsearch/pubsinfo.asp?pubid=2018029

"...nameoffolder/2018029_ascii/FRSS108PUF.dat"

Comment: That file is not a delimited file, it [appears to be fixed-width format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxaNp.png). See [`?read.fwf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.fwf.html) for how to use it.

Comment: Whomever voted to close, it is clearly _not_ "not reproducible", the OP provided the reference link and some code. It is also clearly not a typo. If you're going to vote-to-close, please pick a more appropriate reason.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a "something"-delimited file, it's fixed width.

```r
readLines(unz("~/Downloads/2018029_ascii.zip", "FRSS108PUF.dat"), n=3)
# [1] "100011331 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 5 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 5 1 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 12000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.30382293817.303822938 18.5837245717.927828408 18.5837245718.02058140118.02058140117.92782840818.471095936           0 18.5837245718.471095936 18.5837245718.47109593617.92782840818.36509251618.47109593617.92782840818.47109593618.36509251617.927828408"
# [2] "100022331 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 4 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 4 3 3 2 3 3 4 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 4 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 4 2 2 1 1 3 1 2 1 2 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 2 4 1 4 3 4 3 3 3 2 2 3 1200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.4137039431 5.318726681 5.3187266815.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.4137039431 5.318726681 5.3187266815.33290239175.33290239175.4137039431           0 5.318726681 5.3187266815.41370394315.4137039431 5.3187266815.22702449685.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.39811066135.39811066135.39811066135.41370394315.41370394315.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.2292535051"
# [3] "100032331 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 4 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 3 5 4 4 4 3 4 5 5 5 5 4 4 5 4 4 3 5 2 2 5 1 1 4 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 5 2 2 1 1 3 1 4 3 4 5 2 2 1 1 2 1200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.4137039431 5.318726681 5.3187266815.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.41370394315.4137039431 5.318726681 5.3187266815.33290239175.33290239175.41370394315.4137039431 5.318726681 5.3187266815.41370394315.4137039431 5.3187266815.22702449685.41370394315.4137039431           05.41370394315.41370394315.39811066135.39811066135.39811066135.41370394315.41370394315.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.22925350515.2292535051"
```

The hard part about fixed-width formats is determining the widths of each field. Fortunately (somewhat), the documentation zip has `LayoutPUF.pdf` that contains each field and the columns for each.

The widths for that file should total 1441, since that's what we're getting from the file:

```r
nchar(readLines(unz("~/Downloads/2018029_ascii.zip", "FRSS108PUF.dat"), n=3))
# [1] 1441 1441 1441
```

Counting up the columns, we can use

```r
widths <- c(5, rep(1, 4), rep(2, 73), rep(1, 74), rep(12, 101))
out <- read.fwf(unz("~/Downloads/2018029_ascii.zip", "FRSS108PUF.dat"), widths = widths)
# Warning in readLines(file, n = thisblock) :
#   incomplete final line found on '~/Downloads/2018029_ascii.zip:FRSS108PUF.dat'
str(out)
# 'data.frame': 1527 obs. of  253 variables:
#  $ V1  : int  10001 10002 10003 10004 10005 10006 10007 10008 10009 10010 ...
#  $ V2  : int  1 2 2 3 2 2 1 1 2 3 ...
#  $ V3  : int  3 3 3 2 2 2 4 4 3 2 ...
#  $ V4  : int  3 3 3 1 1 1 2 4 4 2 ...
#  $ V5  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ V6  : int  1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
#  $ V7  : int  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ V8  : int  1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
#  $ V9  : int  1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#   [list output truncated]
```

Over to you to name all 253 columns. You can transcribe from the pdf (you might be able to scrape it, but that doesn't look like an awesome scrape-able pdf), starting with something like

```r
colnames(out) <- c("IDNUMBER", "DSIZCL3", "URBAN", "OEREG", "Q1", "Q2", ...)
```

It will be laborious, no doubt.

---

*Edit*: try this.

```r
m <- pdftools::pdf_text(unz("~/Downloads/2018029_documentation.zip", "LayoutPUF.pdf")) |>
  strsplit("\n") |>
  unlist()
head(m, 20)
#  [1] "U.S. DEPARTMENT OF EDUCATION"                                               "NATIONAL CENTER FOR EDUCATION STATISTICS (NCES)"                           
#  [3] "FAST RESPONSE SURVEY SYSTEM"                                                "CAREER AND TECHNICAL EDUCATION PROGRAMS IN PUBLIC SCHOOL DISTRICTS"        
#  [5] "PUBLIC USE FILE"                                                            ""                                                                          
#  [7] ""                                                                           " Variable Name   Type   Column(s) Description"                             
#  [9] "--------------- ------ ----------- -----------"                             "IDNUMBER         Char    1-5       Random Number assigned to each record"  
# [11] ""                                                                           "DSIZCL3         Num      6        District enrollment size in 3 categories"
# [13] "                                  1 = Less than 2,000"                      "                                  2 = 2,000-4,999"                         
# [15] "                                  3 = 5,000 or more"                        ""                                                                          
# [17] "URBAN           Num      7        Community type"                           "                                  1 = City"                                
# [19] "                                  2 = Suburban"                             "                                  3 = Town"                                
length(m)
# [1] 1323
m[1280:1289]
#  [1] ""                                                                                                           
#  [2] "FWT98    Num   1406-1417 Replicate Weight 98"                                                               
#  [3] ""                                                                                                           
#  [4] "FWT99    Num   1418-1429 Replicate Weight 99"                                                               
#  [5] ""                                                                                                           
#  [6] "FWT100   Num   1430-1441 Replicate Weight 100"                                                              
#  [7] ""                                                                                                           
#  [8] ""                                                                                                           
#  [9] ""                                                                                                           
# [10] ""                                                                                                           

head(m[10:1289])
# [1] "IDNUMBER         Char    1-5       Random Number assigned to each record"   ""                                                                          
# [3] "DSIZCL3         Num      6        District enrollment size in 3 categories" "                                  1 = Less than 2,000"                     
# [5] "                                  2 = 2,000-4,999"                          "                                  3 = 5,000 or more"                       
tail(m[10:1289])
# [1] ""                                              "FWT100   Num   1430-1441 Replicate Weight 100" ""                                             
# [4] ""                                              ""                                              ""                                             
nms <- grep("^\\S+", m[10:1289], value = TRUE) |>
  grep(x = _, "[", fixed = TRUE, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
head(nms)
# [1] "IDNUMBER         Char    1-5       Random Number assigned to each record"                         
# [2] "DSIZCL3         Num      6        District enrollment size in 3 categories"                       
# [3] "URBAN           Num      7        Community type"                                                 
# [4] "OEREG           Num      8        REGION"                                                         
# [5] "Q1    Num   9         Does your district offer CTE programs to students at the high school level?"
# [6] "Q2A   Num   10-11     Does an area/regional CTE center or a group/consortium of school districts" 
head(sub(" .*", "", x = nms))
# [1] "IDNUMBER" "DSIZCL3"  "URBAN"    "OEREG"    "Q1"       "Q2A"     
colnames(out) <- sub(" .*", "", x = nms)
out[1:3, 1:10]
#   IDNUMBER DSIZCL3 URBAN OEREG Q1 Q2A Q2B Q2C Q2D Q2E
# 1    10001       1     3     3  1   1   1   1   1   2
# 2    10002       2     3     3  1   2   1   2   2   2
# 3    10003       2     3     3  1   2   1   1   1   2
```

If you need the questions themselves, you may be able to get some of it from the `nms` object (some `substring` might be useful), though the filtering will leave many of those sentences incomplete.